# Order by sum of elements under a certain label

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a table in R like

```
df = data.frame(name=c("A","B","C","C","B","A"), group=c("X","Y","X","Y","X","Y"),
                      val=c(10,5,1,2,6,12))
```

I want to order the rows by the **sum** of "val" under a given name, and then I want to display the X's above the Y's, so df should look like:

```
name  group  val
A     X      10
A     Y      12
B     X      6
B     Y      5
C     X      1
C     Y      2
```

I have tried something with dplyr like:

```
%>% order(desc(val), group)
```

Which doesnt really work. Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(total = sum(val)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total), group)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange_all()
#  name group val
#1    A     X  10
#2    A     Y  12
#3    B     X   6
#4    B     Y   5
#5    C     X   1
#6    C     Y   2
```

If there are more columns

```
df %>%
    arrange(name, group, val)
```

Comment: This doesn't work? Supposing I have more columns in my df, but the specifications of ordering by column val/name/group still hold, how would one simple call to arrange_all know to order as I specified?

Comment: @RajRaina  I get the expexcted output